# How to remove nested JSON.stringify() properties

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, stringify

I'm trying to modify a string with Typescript. The string is created by the *JSON.stringify()* method.

I want to remove the properties *"id"*, *"lightStatus"* and the *"value"* attributes of *"inputPort"* and *"outputPort"*. (I only need their attribute *"id"*.)

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.light));
// Results in -> {"id":1,"name":"Light Switch","lightStatus":true,"inputPort":{"id":2,"value":0},"outputPort":{"id":2,"value":false},"resistance":100}
```

I tried to do it the following way but it doesn't recognize "inputPort.id" and "outputPort.id". This is what I tried and what it resulted in.

```
var savedLight = JSON.stringify(this.light, ["name", "inputPort.id", "outputPort.id", "resistance"]);
// Results in -> {"name":"Light Switch","resistance":100}
```

The result should include the properties *"name", "inputPort id", "outputPort id" and "resistance"*. Like this:

```
{"name":"Light Switch","inputPort": 2, "outputPort": 2, "resistance":100}
```

Can anyone help me how I can get rid of the unnecessary properties?

Comment: what is the expected json data and what you get from the response. update it clearly.

Comment: @Aravind I added the expected output. The result I got so far doesn't include the "inputPort" and the "outputPort" which is what I would want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a "replacer" function that returns the exact value you want.

```js
var data = {"id":1,"name":"Light Switch","lightStatus":true,"inputPort":{"id":2,"value":0},"outputPort":{"id":2,"value":false},"resistance":100};

var result = JSON.stringify(data, function(k, v) {
    switch (k) {
    case "": case "name": case "resistance":
     return v
    case "inputPort": case "outputPort":
     return v.id
    default:
     return undefined;
  }
}, 2)

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = result
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

The `""` represents the top level object. For that, `"name"`, and `"resistance"`, it simply returns the original value.

For `"inputPort"` and `"outputPort"` it returns the `id` property.

Anything else gets `undefined`, which means it gets omitted from the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a replacer function for this.

```js
var obj = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Light Switch",
  "lightStatus": true,
  "inputPort": {
    "id": 2,
    "value": 0
  },
  "outputPort": {
    "id": 2,
    "value": false
  },
  "resistance": 100
};

var stringified = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, val) {
  if (key === 'id' || key === 'lightStatus') {
    return void(0);
  }
  if (key === 'inputPort' || key === 'outputPort') {
    return val.id;
  }
  return val;
});

console.log(stringified);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `Replacer` function  of `JSON.stringify`

```
var data='{"id":1,"name":"Light Switch","lightStatus":true,"inputPort":{"id":2,"value":0},"outputPort":{"id":2,"value":false},"resistance":100}';
var json=JSON.parse(data);

function replacer(i, val) {
  switch (i) {
    case "": case "name": case "resistance":
        return val
    case "inputPort": case "outputPort":
        return val.id
    default:
        return undefined;
  }

}

console.log(JSON.stringify(json,replacer));
```